# ¿Qué es y que utilidad tiene super en POO?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.x

Soy nuevo en Django y Python en  general y me ha surgido una duda en la siguiente  línea de código:

> queryset = super(EjemploListView, self).get_queryset()

no tengo claro que función tiene `super` en ella.

El  código de la clase dónde está esta línea es el siguiente:

```
class EjemploListView(ListView):
    model = Ejemplo
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(EjemploListView, self).get_queryset()
        filter = self.request.GET.get('filter')
        if filter == 'add':
           queryset = queryset.filter(data=0)
        elif filter== 'del':
           queryset = queryset.filter(data=1)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`super` (nombre que deriva de "**super**class") tiene la siguiente sintaxis general:

```
super(subClase, instancia).método(argumentos)
```

En Python 3 tanto la clase como la instancia se pasan de forma automática a `super`, por lo que se puede hacer simplemente:

```
super().método(argumentos)
```

Básicamente es un shortcut que permite acceder a la clase base de una clase derivada y delegar llamadas a métodos de esta, sin tener que conocer ni escribir el nombre de la clase base. Retorna un objeto proxy, que permite actuar como un camino de llamada a métodos de alguna clase padre, no retorna una referencia a la clase padre en si misma.

En este caso se usa para llamar al método `get_queryset()` de la clase padre `ListView`.

Podemos verlo con un ejemplo muy simple:

```
class Padre:
    def foo(self):
        return 13


class Hija(Padre):
    def foo(self):
        return 0

    def bar(self):
        n = super(Hija, self).foo()
        return n

inst = Hija()
print(inst.bar()) # 13
print(inst.foo()) # 0
```

Como se puede ver, con `super(Hija, self).foo()` se llama la método `foo` de la clase padre independientemente de que lo hemos sobrescrito en la clase hija. Esto es muy importante ala hora de llamar al inicializador de una clase padre y pasarle los argumentos necesarios al instanciar una clase hija.

En el caso de la herencia simple, como en este caso, sería equivalente a `n = Padre.foo(self)`. La principal ventaja es no tener que especificar el nombre de la clase padre, lo que facilita el mantenimiento del código.

---

En la herencia múltiple, en cambio,  es donde muestra su verdadero potencial y tiene una relación intima con el método de resolución del orden de la herencia. Veamos un ejemplo muy simple:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("Método foo desde clase A")


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("Método foo desde clase B")


class C(A):
    pass


class D(C, B):
    def bar(self):
        super(D, self).foo()

inst = D()
inst.bar() # Método foo desde clase B
```

En este caso `D` hereda de `C` y de `B`, que a su vez heredan de `A`. Al hacer `super().foo()` desde `D` nos encontramos con que se llama al método `foo` de la clase `B` ¿Por qué?

Bien, Python tiene un mecanismo conocido como MRO (**M**ethod **R**esolution **O**rder) que especifica el orden de la herencia y que determina que método heredar si tenemos dos clases padre con el mismo método entre otras cosas, por ejemplo `D` hereda el método `foo` de `C`, no de `B` o `A`. Podemos ver este orden consultando el atributo `__mro__` que tiene toda clase.

`super` busca el primer método `foo` que encuentra entre las clases de las que hereda siguiendo el orden establecido por el MRO. En nuestro caso, el MRO indica lo siguiente:

```
>>> print([clase.__name__ for clase in D.__mro__])
>>> ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'object']
```

Por tanto, primero busca en `C`, que no implementa el método (solo lo hereda de `A`). Al no encontrarlo en `C`, lo busca en `B` en el que si lo encuentra y lo llama. Si no lo encontrara pasaría a `A` y seguiría hasta llegar a `object`. La herencia múltiple es un tema complejo y que se sale del ámbito de la pregunta, pero esto es un ejemplo del papel de `super` en ella y que justifica su existencia. Uno de los problemas más conocidos que trata de resolver `super` es el llamado ["problema del diamante"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_diamante).

Comment: Gracias hermano

Comment: Gracias por la detallada respuesta @FJServilla ¿Tienes la fuente de esta información?

Answer (score 1):

Significa que está llamando al método `get_queryset()` de la superclase `ListView`. Es herencia de clases: `EjemploListView` hereda de `ListView` el método `getqueryset()`, pero se vuelve a implementar dicho método en `EjemploListView` para sobreescribir su comportamiento, por lo que para llamar al método de la superclase con el mismo nombre debes usar `super()` o se llamará recursivamente a sí mismo desde dentro del método una y otra vez.

No sólo aparece en Django sino que es una función del lenguaje Python. [Aquí puedes ver más información](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/classes.html#herencia-multiple).

Comment: Gracias hermano