# Uso de atributo de instancia heredado de la clase padre

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, herencia

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic


class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)
        self.preview_alta #QpushButton

class image_anadir(Primera):
    def __init__(self):
        pr = Primera()
        pr.preview_alta.clicked.connect(lambda:print("add"))

app = QApplication([])
p = Primera()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Dentro de la clase `Primera` que hereda de `QMainWindow` tengo un botón `self.preview_alta`, pero necesito ocupar ese botón en la clase `image_anadir`.

Sin embargo, no ejecuta la acción que le indico dentro de la clase `image_anadir`.

¿En qué me equivoqué?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tienes algo de confusión con el paradigma y conceptos de la POO, básicamente tienes dos problemas:

- **En ningún momento instancias la clase `image_añadir`**, solo creas un objeto de `Primera` (`p = Primera`), por lo que para empezar nada de lo que hagas en `image_añadir` se va a ver en ningún sitio porque no la instancias. Ten en cuenta que una clase por si sola es solo un esquema o plantilla que se usa para crear objetos y que la herencia solo trabaja en una dirección, la clase hija hereda las características de la clase (o clases) padre pero nunca a la inversa.
- **A la hora de crear tu clase `image_añadir` te quedas entre un intento de herencia y uno de composición** sin completar ninguna de las dos, si vas a usar herencia no instancies a la clase padre dentro del inicializador de la clase hija.

  La clase `image_añadir` al heredar de `Primera` obtiene sus métodos y atributos incluidos el `__init__` y `preview_alta`.

  Ahora bién, en tu clase hija **sobreescribes el inicializador (`__init__)` heredado del padre**, **para poder hacer uso de los atributos definidos en el inicializador de la clase superior tienes que llamarlo explícitamente en el inicializador de clase derivada**. Esto permitirá que todas las tareas necesarias para inicializar correctamente la instancia se lleven a cabo y que todos los atributos definidos en el inicializador de la clase padre  sean inicializados correctamente y pasen a estar disponibles en la clase derivada (como la carga del .ui, sin la cual el atributo `preview_alta` no existirá). Es exactamente lo mismo que has hecho en `Primera` con `QMainWindow.__init__(self)`. Con ello puedes usar tu botón heredado como harías en `Primera`:

  `self.preview_alta.clicked.connect(lambda:print("add"))`:

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic



class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui", self)


class ImageAnadir(Primera):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Primera.__init__(self)
        self.preview_alta.clicked.connect(lambda: print("add"))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = ImageAnadir()           # Instancia de la subclase.
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`super` permite hacer referencia a la clase padre y llamar al método `__init__` de la misma como también hace `Primera.__init__(self)`, tiene especial utilidad en casos de herencia múltiple. Para más información puede ser útil:

[¿Qué es y que utilidad tiene super en POO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130241/15089)

Como recomendación, considera nombrar las clases comenzando por mayúscula y usando CamelCase como se recomienda en [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), esto diferencia las clases de métodos/funciones y variables.

---

### Edición:

En referencia al comentario, que la clase esté o no definida en otro módulo no tiene importancia en cuanto a usar herencia o composición. Imaginemos que `Principal` está definida en un módulo llamado `interfaz.py`, suponiendo que esté en el mismo directorio que el script donde definimos `ImageAnadir`, basta con importar la clase con:

```
from interfaz import Principal
```

para poder usarla.

En cuanto a un ejemplo de composición, la composición a grandes rasgos quiere decir que nuestra clase instancia otras clases y maneja estos objetos para implementar las funcionalidades deseadas.

El usar herencia o composición (o agregación...) va a depender de nuestro caso concreto. Imaginemos que tenemos la clase `Mamifero`  y la clase `Gato`, lo lógico es que `Gato` herede de `Mamífero` porque un gato **es** un mamífero (y lo será siempre). Si tenemos una clase `Barco` y una clase `Vela` lo lógico es usar composición porque un barco **tiene** una vela que usa para navegar, no es una vela, es más, un barco puede no tener una vela y seguir siendo un barco. Si, son ejemplos muy claros y en la realidad los límites no están tan claros siempre, peros esas dos verbos (**ser** y **tener**) son de gran ayuda.

Dado que no tengo ni idea de que intentas hacer, solo voy a dejar un ejemplo muy simple de composición con tus clases, que no se si tendrán en realidad algún sentido dada la falta de contexto:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication
from interfaz import Primera



class ImageAnadir:                 # No hereda de Principal
    def __init__(self): 
        self._interfaz = Primera() # Instancia un objeto de la clase Principal
        self._interfaz.preview_alta.clicked.connect(self.obtener_imagen)

    def obtener_imagen(self):
        print("Imágen obtenida...")

    def abrir_ventana(self):
        self._interfaz.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
im = ImageAnadir()
im.abrir_ventana()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ,podrias apoyarme con unjemplo de composision, suponiendo que imagenAnadir estuviera en otro modulo

Comment: @Rs_sky he editado la respuesta, mira a ver que tal.

Comment: Gracias te entendi mas que a mi profesor :)