# Python: POO y tkinter

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

estoy convirtiendo los programas que ya he hecho en python a programas utilizando el paradigma de programacion POO, al hacer esto me surgen ciertas dudas, Adjunto mi codigo aqui:

```
import tkinter as tk 

class Calculadora(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Calculadora")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = Calculadora(root = tk.Tk())
    App.mainloop()
```

¿Porque al instanciar la clase Calculadora y pasarle como argumento `root = tk.Tk` crea la ventana?

¿Porque la clase Calculadora debe heredar de `tk.Frame`?

¿Porque al usar el metodo `super()` tengo que llamar a root si este es parte del constructor de la clase Calculadora? , no se supone que `super()` es para heredar los atributos y demas de la clase padre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Por qué al instanciar la clase `Calculadora` y pasarle como argumento `root = tk.Tk` crea la ventana?

La ventana se crea porque instancias `tk.Tk`, clase base para cualquier aplicación de Tkinter y que inicia el intérprete TCL y el ciclo de eventos. Es decir, lo que inicia la ventana es  `tk.Tk()`. Luego, para que el `Frame` de tu clase `Calculadora` pueda dibujarse en la ventana principal debes pasarle una instancia de esta ventana principal o una instancia de otro widget que ya pertenezca a esta ventana si fuera un widget anidado. Es exactamente lo mismo que cuando haces `tk.Button(parent, text=...)` por ejemplo.

`App.mainloop()` es el método de `tk.Tk` encargado de iniciar el ciclo de eventos y por tanto de mostrar la ventana. Dicho método lo hereda `Calculadora` de `tk.Frame` que en esencia llama al método `mainloop` de la ventana principal.

Realmente no es imprescindible pasar una instancia de `tk.Tk`, si no lo haces implícitamente se genera una instancia de la misma a la que puedes acceder desde la instancia del `Frame` mediante el atributo `master`:

```
import tkinter as tk 

class Calculadora(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.master.title("Calculadora")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Calculadora()
    app.mainloop()
```

> ¿Por qué la clase `Calculadora` debe heredar de `tk.Frame`?

No tendría por qué heredar de `tk.Frame`, podría heredar de `tk.Toplevel`, `tk.Button`, `tk.Canvas`, etc. O no heredar de nada y en vez de herencia usar composición, todo depende de cómo queramos estructurar la app.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Calculadora:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("100x100")
        self.master_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.master_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.root.title("Calculadora")
        btn = tk.Button(self.master_frame, text="Hola")
        btn.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Calculadora(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

`tk.Frame` es un widget básico, representa simplemente una región rectangular en la pantalla con solo un puñado de características  o atributos básicos (color de fondo, margenes, padding, bordes, etc). Esto lo hace muy útil como widget base para cualquier otro widget que queramos implementar o como contenedor de otros widgets. Esta es la raźón por la que se suele heredar de `tk.Frame`, tu clase `Calculadora` al heredar de `tk.Frame` se convierte en un widget de Tkinter herendando con ello sus atributos y métodos, entre ellos `pack`, `grid` y `place` por ejemplo.

> ¿Por qué al usar el método `super()` tengo que llamar a `root` si este es parte del constructor de la clase `Calculadora`? , no se supone que `super()` es para heredar los atributos y demás de la clase padre?

En `super().__init__(root)` no llamas a `root`, lo que haces es **pasar al método `__init__` de la clase padre (`tk.Frame`) la instancia de la ventana principal** para que tu clase pueda ser inicializada de forma correcta (y que entre otras cosas no cree una instancia `tk.Tk` implícita como hemos visto).

Al tener `Calculadora` un método `__init__` definido se sobrescribe el heredado de `tk.Frame`. Si no llamas al método `__init__` del padre todas las tareas esenciales de inicialización que se llevan a cabo en él no tendrán lugar y simplemente tu clase `Calculadora` será inútil porque no va a ser algo que se comporte como un widget de tkinter.

Para más información de que es y que hace `super` ver:

- [¿Qué es y que utilidad tiene super en POO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130241/15089)