# 'super' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django

Alguien puede ayudarme con este error en Django con python 2.7. Estoy tratando con este codigo implementar un calendario.
Estoy teniendo un error en la variable context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
Nose que estoy haciendo mal.

```
 from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import *
from .utils import Calendar

class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'agendas/templates/calendar.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CalendarView,self)

    # use today's date for the calendar
    d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('day', None))

    # Instantiate our calendar class with today's year and date
    cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)

    # Call the formatmonth method, which returns our calendar as a table
    html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
    context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
    return context

def get_date(req_day):
    if req_day:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_day.split('-'))
        return date(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.datetime.today()
```

El error en el log de Django

```
    'super' object does not support item assignment
    context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
```

Aqui esta descrito la variable context.

```
<super: <class 'CalendarView'>, <CalendarView object>>
d   datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 25, 23, 26, 52, 368050)
self    <comutechapps.agendas.views.CalendarView object at 0x7fbb7d6d0250>
cal     <comutechapps.agendas.utils.Calendar object at 0x7fbb79e94a90>
html_cal    '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n{self.formatweekheader()}\n{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
kwargs {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la línea:

```
context = super(CalendarView,self)
```

[`super`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130241/15089) devuelve un objeto proxy que delega llamadas de método a una clase padre siguiendo el MRO. No es la clase misma. En tu caso `contex` por tanto es simplemente un objeto tipo `super`, por lo que cuando posteriormente haces:

```
context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
```

intentas asignar a la clave `calendar` y `super` no es ningún contenedor que defina el método `__getitem__` como es `dict`, por lo que tienes el error mencionado.

El problema es que te falta la llamada al método de la clase padre:

```
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

o si aún usas Python 2.x:

```
context = super(CalendarView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```